# Element based native scrolling in iOS5

Tags: html, ios, css, ios5

I'm building a mobile web app and would like to know how to use the new css native scrolling feature in iOS 5 where I only enable scrolling to an element within a webpage.

The page itself is locked and not scrollable/movable but only the chosen element is scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague. 
Have you tried putting the following styles on your desired element?;

```
 overflow: scroll;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

And on the document body;

```
 overflow:hidden;
```

Could you explain what the actual problem you're encountering is?
And maybe provide a short example.

Comment: open this in mobile safari: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1928164/ios5/index.html the entire page moves when you scroll over. I want to lock the page in place and only make the list scrollable like in a native app.

Comment: disable the rubber band scrolling behavior for the page but enable that for a specific element in the page

Comment: I hate to say it, but I get the exact expected result you described.

Comment: Sometimes if you're at the top and try to scroll up, the whole page moves. But if I move down slightly before scrolling up, it works fine.

Comment: What if you put scroll="no" in the body tag? Won't it fix that problem? I'm really not sure about it, but you should give it a try.